# Manually zoom or search for their image in the mosaic

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, mosaic

Need to stream in images & captions from Instagram and pull it all into a mosaic. Users will then be able to manually zoom in or search for their image in the mosaic.

Please refer to the reference below,
http://www.h-d-mosaic.com/

Thanks in Advance